# Linux KDE Debian 10 Buster Install - Blender 2.80 Exec Format Error

Tags: error, installation

I just installed Debian 10. I've downloaded Blender 2.80 64-bit from the official site. When I double click the "blender" executable nothing happens. When I open a terminal in the same folder and run *./blender*, I get the following error *./blender: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error*. I've got a 64-bit installation.

How can I fix this error?
Thanks

Comment: Have you downloaded Blender for Linux 64-Bit? Perhaps you accidentally downloaded the Windows version. The file should be https://www.blender.org/download/Blender2.80/blender-2.80-linux-glibc217-x86_64.tar.bz2/

Comment: Hi, yes, I have verified that I've downloaded for Linux, and the 64-bit version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

linux do not use .EXE extensions to run applications, and do not use binaries very often if they are not necessary, you wrong to download blender because I do not download it from LINUX, blender org identifies your system and your generals from your pc, it is quite intrusive, and gives you the right version for your pc and system

### and this would be the manual way to get blender for debian 64 bits

***NOTE:***
*DEBIAN & UBUNTU they have blender maintainers check both distributions pages and you can install the DEB file for your system*

[image]

use este enlace

### [Install Blender on your Linux distribution](https://snapcraft.io/blender)

[image]

### [DEBIAN BLENDER 2.8](https://snapcraft.io/install/blender/debian)

[image]

Comment: Hi, yeah I've downloaded the correct one for Linux on blender.org/download. It automatically took me to the download option for Linux. When I extracted it, I ran the blender - the gear icon file.

Comment: Also, I don't see a deb file. When I right click and go to properties it says _application/x-executable_

Comment: Do you have experience with Linux?

Comment: Yes, I had been using Ubuntu for about 5 years. But it's been about 3 years since I've used it. However, I'm now on Debian with KDE. The Ubuntu ppa and Software Centre made stuff really easy but I felt it was too bloated so I switched.

Comment: well ... I need to review many things what I ask is almost implicit and the solution is in the same question, if I use debian! Where do I have to go find my application? to debian of course! debian has in its official list a list of application maintainers that are available for debian

Comment: check the answer once more and use the link you provide, and don't forget to rate the question as accepted that helps to know if I solve your question

Comment: Dude! You are amazing. Thanks for the help. But it seems like a Blender build for  i386 architecture is not available. It get the following error message _error: snap "blender" is not available on stable for this architecture (i386) but exists on other architectures (amd64)._

Comment: @Ryan if your architecture is i386 you're not running a 64-bit system. Try the 32-bit version (https://www.blender.org/download/Blender2.80/blender-2.80-linux-glibc224-i686.tar.bz2/)

Comment: @Ryan Do you know how to compile software ?, You can compile your own distro, I do not currently have my lap available to compile applications but I can guide you

Comment: @RyanIn your question you have never mentioned that you need a 32-bit version, it should be mentioned since rjg also provided 64-bit links, because I did not mention that you need a 32 bis or **i386 version**

Comment: the version that they are giving you is a .TAR file that will not help you at all if you do not know how to build a deb file, in conclusion when you see that your experience with Linux is limited, it does not help much what they are showing you, because do not ask in UBUNTU.ORG, surely they have a 32-bit version that is 100% compatible with debian, since ubuntu is derived from debian compatibility is a complete

Comment: I am so sorry. That was such a stupid mistake on my part. Thanks. It works.

Comment: no problem I am looking for a 32-bit version for debian, but my best advice is that you read the documentation to build blender on your pc and when you have installed the dependencies let me know and I will guide you to do it, but not here, because it is another topic different

Comment: Try reading this [To get the latest Blender successfully running on Linux system, follow a few simple steps.](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender/Linux/Ubuntu)